# How was the return on investment calculated

Tags: economics

This result was found in [What Would You Pay for an Extra Year of Life?](https://blog.sterlingfoundations.com/2024/01/02/what-would-you-pay-for-an-extra-year-of-life/comment-page-1/#comments). But how was the 5.8% calculated?

Here is the excerpt:

> What’s the Return on Investment? I know there’s a lot more involved in
> exercising than merely putting in hours. But to keep the analysis
> tractable, I want to look at the investment “now” of hours into
> exercise, for the payoff of more years of life “later.” We can use the
> standard tools of present value analysis, except the “currency” is
> hours, not dollars.
>
> Let’s make some base-case assumptions.
>
> The most important assumptions are:
>
> A 50 year old male who doesn’t exercise can expect to live to age 80
>
> That same male who puts in 8 hours per week of exercise can expect to
> live to age 88.
>
> We will measure investment and return in terms of hours per year
>
> We assume people value their waking hours, and sleep 8 hours a night.
> We don’t count the 8 hours of sleep as “return” though you of course
> could decide to do so.
>
> The exercise continues every year, even after age 80
>
> The exercise costs only the time allocated to it and provides only the
> expected extra years of life (i.e. no “disutility” or “utility” except
> the expected life extension benefit)
>
> Everything else is constant
>
> Given these assumptions, we can compute a “rate of return” just as we
> would with dollars. When we do so we find that the return on
> investment is 5.8%.

Here are my calculations:

I got a different value, exactly half, actually.

I’m wondering if my parameters are correct:

Hours gained: 8 years * 365 days/year * 16 hours/day = 46,720 hrs.

Hours exercised: 8 hours/week * 52 weeks/year * 38 years = 15,808 hrs.

ROI = 46,720/15,808 = 2.96.
A
Annualized Return = 2.96^(1/38)=1.029, so 2.9%, which is half of 5.8%.

To get AR of 5.8%, the ROI should be 1.058^38 = 8.52.

Also, here is the [Present Value, using Google Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJjeg.jpg).

Comment: Do you know how to do a PV analysis (EG to value a company)? If yes, set up the equation for "hours", and solve for $r$.

Comment: I did, but I got a different value, exactly half, actually. I’m wondering if my parameters are correct: hours gained: 8 years * 365 days/year * 16 hours/day = 46,720 hrs. Hours exercised: 8 hours/week * 52 weeks/year * 38 years = 15,808 hrs. So the ROI is 46,720/15,808=2.96. And the Annual return is 2.96^(1/38)=1.029, so 2.9%, which is half of 5.8%.

Comment: You did not do a Present Value analysis. You did a sort-of nominal value analysis, or at least one where you combined all of the costs to year 1, and the revenue to year 30.

Comment: So how would I do the PV analysis correctly? Which values should I use?